# Absolute positioned div width/height in IE (all versions)

Tags: css

My knowledge of css is very limited.  In a larger context, I need to do something like the following:

Inner div goes inside other divs.  I am trying to position the inner div, offset from the browser window and with a size that is certain percentage of the browser window.  So I apply the following css to the inner div

```
.abs_pos {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This works on Chrome and Firefox.  But on IE (all version), the inner div's width becomes a percentage of the immediate outer div and not that of the browser window, while the height appears to be determined based on the content of the inner div.

I have the link here to the sample html file.
http://orissaclassifieds.com/pos.html

So how can I make this work?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It appears to work (in IE) if the height/width are given in pixels.  If the height/width are in percentage, it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code should work, but you are using an invalid/incomplete doctype which is sending IE into quirks mode.

For HTML4.01 Transitional it should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

However, a much shorter/simpler doctype to use is HTML5's. It will trigger standards mode in all browsers:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works on IE7 and IE8.  Not on IE6.  It is perhaps a problem with IE6?

Comment: @rpat I believe IE6 doesn't support that doctype

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work in all browsers by making the parent div have a css rule:

```
position:relative;
```

Comment: If I did that the div would be inside the immediate parent div.  I need to see if I can do this relative to the browser window.  What I have works fine with Chrome/Firefox. I need to understand why the behavior is different in IE.

Answer (score 0):

excuse me, but i don't understand why you use percentage for every parameter, also width and height inside another div... unless the main container is the body page. In your case i should use pixels, and if the div is placed into another div you can use relative instead of absolute...that is relative to the container where you're into...hope this helps

Comment: If it percentage it is better, as the div gets re-sized when the browser is re-sized.  If the outer div position is set to relative, things would be relative to the immediate outer div.  I need this relative to the browser window.  I would prefer not to use fixed position. I would like to know why the behaviour is different in IE.

Comment: the browser resizes...OK, but you're assuming you're inside another div, or am i wrong? You have to decide the behaviour/position of the outer div first...and then adjust the inner according to that. bye

Comment: I need to treat the div as independent even though it is inside another div.  What I read absolute positioning allows this.  Works in other browsers, not IE